What does Apache's 'require all' default to?
Dumb question - what does require all default to? Specifically, if I have a simple site with no require directives, is it accessible? I've been through the Apache mod_authz_core and Access HowTo docs and can't find the answer.
Note that Deb-type systems have an apache2.conf which includes
<Directory />
    Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

I'm only interested in sites where this isn't applied - if your site is at /var/www1, for example.

The last line in your question implies you are asking about /var/www1 w.r.t. the conf above it. I understand from your comment that you are actually looking for documented evidence that the removal of the  <Directory />Require all denied</Directory> block defaults to granted.
